# Частицы в оценочно-бытийных номинативных предложениях

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор, терминология

Оценочно-бытийные номинативные предложения обязательно должны содержать частицы? Или разные лингвисты по-разному определяют границы этого понятия?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Я прочитала эту тему у Розенталя в книге "Современный русский язык". Он подробно описывает область применения номинативных предложений, но делит их на **бытийные  и указательные**.

Оценочные предложения он номинативными не считает, а относит их к неполным двусоставным, в которых сущ. в И.п. является сказуемым. Также он говорит о  **тесной связи** таких предложений с предыдущим высказыванием.

2) **Кустова (Синтаксис современного русского языка)** рассматривает эти предложения вместе с номинативными, но называет их **оценочно-характеризующими** (а не оценочно-бытийными). Она также соотносит их со сказуемым в двусоставных предложениях, а не с подлежащим. У нее есть такой пример: *Был у меня знакомый. **Удивительный человек**!*  В этом предложении частиц нет.

3) **В другом источнике** дается такая информация:

Оценочно-бытийные предложения объединяют предложения субстантивного типа, в которых значение бытийности сопровождается оценкой. **Структурной особенностью этих предложений являются эмоционально-экспрессивные частицы: ну, то-то, тоже мне, а еще, да и, и же, что за, какой, ай да, прямо и др.:** Ну уж и болезнь! (Л. Т.); И птица же! Кроха, а не птица (Г. Тр.); А еще и дворянин (Г.);

Оценочные предложения делятся на две группы: 1) **предложения с оценочными существительными** (Какой вздор!; Что за чушь!); 2) **предложения с неоценочными существительными** (Ай да парень!; Вот так гости!; Тоже мне компания!).

Общее оценочное значение таких предложений создастся лексическими, морфологическими и синтаксическими средствами. https://studfiles.net/preview/3488542/page:2/

4) Таким образом, можно считать, что частицы и прочие средства — это **характерный признак** оценочных предложений, но в принципе они не являются обязательными.

В то же время,  следует, вероятно,  различать **оценочно-бытийные и оценочно-характеризующие** конструкции. Первый вариант – это самостоятельные **номинативные предложения** (оценка наблюдателя), а второй вариант — это, скорее всего, **номинативы**, тесно связанные с предыдущим текстом. Возможно, частицы в большей степени характерны именно для **оценочно-бытийных** номинативных предложений.